# How can i find the path of tempfile in django

Tags: python, django

I am using pdftk like this

**pdftk** `template.pdf`  **fill_form** `/temp/input.fdf output` `/temp/output.pdf`

Now this is working fine

But now i have generated the temporary file instead of /temp/input.fdf with this

```
myfile = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile()
myfile.write(fdf)
myfile.seek(0)
myfile.close()
```

Now i don't know how can i pass myfile as input to the pdftk

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`myfile.name` will get you the file path.

Note that `tempfile`s do not exist after `close()`. From the docs:

```
 tempfile.TemporaryFile([mode='w+b'[, bufsize=-1[, suffix=''[, 
    prefix='tmp'[, dir=None]]]]])
```

> Return a file-like object that can be used as a temporary storage
>   area. The file is created using mkstemp(). It will be destroyed as
>   soon as it is closed (including an implicit close when the object is
>   garbage collected). Under Unix, the directory entry for the file is
>   removed immediately after the file is created. Other platforms do not
>   support this; your code should not rely on a temporary file created
>   using this function having or not having a visible name in the file
>   system.

*Source: http://docs.python.org/2/library/tempfile.html*

Comment: Thats all right . i will not close it but how can i pass that as argument

Comment: `myfile.name` is what you want

Comment: I have worked that out.I am making the user download that file with diff name. when can i call the close function. or system will delete it after sometime

Comment: @user825904 You will definitely need to call the close function, probably after you are done reading its contents.

Comment: @YuvalAdam I think NamedTemporaryFile is what the OP needs, rather than TemporaryFile

Answer (score 8):

Can't you get the name using

```
myfile = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile()
myfile.write(fdf)
myfile.seek(0)
myfile.close()
print(myfile.name)
```

Comment: If you close myfile at that point, it will likely be deleted immediately, and you won't be able to use it any further. https://docs.python.org/2/library/tempfile.html

However, if you call NamedTemporaryFile with the delete parameter set to False, that problem should be fixed.